# Duplicate question by same user in other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion

[Complex Data Type in C Producing Trouble in Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117518/complex-data-type-in-c-producing-trouble-in-algorithm)
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16290/complex-numbers-in-c-resulting-in-unstable-calculation

I cannot vote to close.

Comment: If nothing else, consider leaving comments linking to the other versions of the question.  Besides helping the mods sort things out, you also keep potential answerers from wasting their time repeating something covered in another answer and help anyone arriving from Google find the other questions.

Answer (score 5):

Ug.  Thought I recognized that title.

This was originally posted on Programmers.SE and migrated to SO.  The user that posted it on P.SE was [user139632](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/139632/user139632).  We try to avoid migrating duplicate questions that are somewhere else on the network that shouldn't be posted on Programmers.SE in the first place (unless they have answers in which case its even *more* fun).  It just makes more work to clean up.

So... this user *doesn't* have an account on SO.

And then, [user11887](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/11887/user11887) (unregistered) on SciComp.SE also posted the same question.  That's a mess.

So, the question really is, who should have it and who wants to dup and merge them?  Is this a SO question? or a SciComp one?

Since SciComp is beta, I would believe the most proper thing to do would be to migrate it to SO since one of the questions is already here (and if the user posts a *third* time, it would likely be on SO anyways).  Otherwise, it would be a ping a moderator here to clear the migration and migrate it there.  Its probably the least work to collect them here rather than there.

For that, one would need to get a hold of one of the SciComp mods so that they can toss it over here.

But yea... aren't identical cross site dups fun?

Comment: Thanks - I see this on other forums, and questions from those forums (not stackExachnge, maybe UNIX.com) over here as well.  I have been leaving those alone.  Bad idea?

Comment: @jimmcnamara I am [of the opinion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243851/213963) that identical questions on multiple sites makes a mess.  It wastes multiple people's time (people trying to solve an already solved question, people trying to find *the* answer to a problem they have) and lowers the value proposition of Stack Exchange.  I really believe that consolidating identical questions on one site is a good thing.  If, however, they are properly tailored for each site, well, they aren't identical anymore.

Comment: ... there's nothing preventing someone from posting their question to multiple ***non*** SE sites, other than that I think that they won't get as good an answer on other sites and if they want a discussion instead of an answer, it's likely not a good SE question in the first place.