# How to report user posting same question on several Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

For example, the same question was posted by the same user on:

- Stack Overflow: [How to use IO Buffer with defined location in VHDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796722/how-to-use-io-buffer-with-defined-location-in-vhdl)
- Electrical Engineering: [How to use IO Buffer with defined location in VHDL?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/how-to-use-io-buffer-with-defined-location-in-vhdl)

I would like to suggestion that the question is closed on Stack Overflow, but there appears to be no appropriate close option.

In "close" there is "off-topic because..." => "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", but there is then no choice for "Electrical Engineering" site.

Alternatively, I could try "close" with "duplicate of...", but then the reference must be a question on Stack Overflow and that question must have upvotes.

So how to handle this kind of duplication ?

This question is somehow similar to [Duplicate question by same user in other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277807/duplicate-question-by-same-user-in-other-stack-exchange-sites), but there was no sharp answer, so I think it is relevant to consider some option under "close" to handle this case.

Comment: Presumably the question is off topic on one of the two sites.  Close it as off topic on whichever site it's off topic on.

Comment: Thanks, closing with "off-topic because..." => "other", and link to crosspost at "Electrical Engineering".

Comment: If it's actually off topic just explain why it's off topic.  There's no need to mention a cross post.  It's not off topic because there is a cross post, it's off topic because its not in the site's scope.

Comment: Well, I would add a downvote too for prioritising getting an answer above wasting contributors' time.

Comment: @Servy: There is a certain overlap between "Stack Overflow" and "Electrical Engineering" sites, because hardware for FPGA/ASIC is written with hardware description languages (HDL) like VHDL, so one can argue if a certain question belongs to the one site or the other.  But my point is that the question should at least not be raised at *both* sites, thus when such a question is spotted it should be closed at one of the sites.  But I raised this question since I was unable to find a proper "close" feature for this case.

Comment: See the MSE FAQ [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) for additional discussion.