# What should I do when a post is cross-posted on external site and abandoned on SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, cross-posting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074731/make-a-nice-figure-with-matlabs-quiver-plot-with-axes-in-different-scales#comment123927605_70074731) is also posted on an external website (not Stack Exchange network) devoted to the programming language. The OP put the link in the question, but didn't explicitly state that it is a cross-posting link. The question is answered on the external site but not here. However, the OP didn't update that information, so I left a comment saying the question has been answered.

I know there are many debates about cross-posting on external sites, like [this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site/141824#141824) and [this one on SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281863/how-to-report-user-posting-same-question-on-several-stack-exchange-sites). I think it is definitely not right to abandon other posts after receiving an answer on one of them.

What is the best thing to do with this kind of posts?

Options I come up with are:

- Edit/Comment to say the question is solved elsewhere with a link to the answer.
  Although obviously the link might be broken or deleted in the future. This will also leave the question unanswered.
- Post the answer as a community wiki, with credit to the original answer.
- Raise a flag for mod's attention.

Comment: Still the Stack Exchange network or really an external site?

Comment: @JeanneDark  Does it mean that there's not much we can do to prevent this kind of actions in the future?

Comment: Prevent what? Cross-posting is a problem when confined to the SE network, eg. asking a question on SO and reposting it also on another SE site where it's on-topic. But when it was posted somewhere else and received an answer, that's not a problem and also not a reason to flag for mod. We also do not need to wait for the OP to come back and provide an answer.

Comment: I am not against cross-posting, but abandoning the post is wasting the time of those who try to answer it, especially for debugging questions.

Comment: SO is not a free, personal help desk. Questions should be helpful to future visitors. Helping the OP is actually just a (nice) side effect. Only when they cross-post in the SE network do they waste other SE users' time. When the answer can be found elsewhere on the Internet, the info can also be added to our repository of programming knowledge (for sure, attribute correctly etc.).

Comment: What's to say a better answer doesn't get posted in the SO version? Why would that be wasting people's time any more than multiple answers to same question on one site? You seem to be implying that something nefarious is going on. There is zero need for moderator involvement here

Comment: @Miscellaneous "*but abandoning the post is wasting the time of those who try to answer it*" neither of these things is a problem. 1. "abandoning the post" is meaningless. If the question *is answerable*, then the only difference OP makes is accepting an answer. Acceptance is not a useful criteria anyway. The question should be useful to everybody, not just OP, therefore the acceptance hardly matters. 2. Nobody "wastes time" by answering a question. Again, it's useful ***for everybody***. If OP is not around that's one person out of potential hundreds or even thousands.

Comment: Folks, care to elaborate on what is unclear about this question? It might have an easy answer, but come on, "details or clarity"?

Comment: Third party content is third party content. Doesn't matter if questions are repeated there. Just treat it as you would treat any other external resource. You basically commented "Solved elsewhere on the Internet", which is fine and helpful (IMHO), but won't help SO directly. SO wants to stand on its own.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Edit/Comment to say the question is solved elsewhere with a link to the answer. Although obviously the link might be broken or deleted in the future. This will also leave the question unanswered.

This **will not** answer the question.

Editing the question to say it has been answered should never be done. We have an answer box for that.

Leaving a comment is iffy but if the link contains an answer, we also have an answer box where it can fit.

> Raise a flag for mod's attention.

This **will not** answer the question.

*At most*, a mod can close or delete a question. However, that is not appropriate if the question is in scope and belongs on the network. We do not close or delete questions because they happen to have been answered on a secondary place.

> Post the answer as a community wiki, with credit to the original answer.

This **will** answer the question.

Whether or not it is made community wiki is not very relevant. It is certainly "good practice" but not mandated.

Write an answer with a link to the source, and quote relevant parts of it. Try to support it with extra information and give credit where it is due.

This ensures that the question posted on Stack Overflow remains useful for the future.

Comment: What if there are multiple good answers on other external sites? Is it ok to put them all in one single answer?

Comment: Depends. You can try to put them in the same answer but you can also split them up in different answers. The latter is useful to allow each solution to be ranked individually against the other. If the solutions are close and/or similar, one answer might suffice.

Comment: If splitting them up into separate answers, I do recommend making them community wikis - otherwise it would look like you are trying to get extra reputation by potentially receiving multiple upvotes from each reader - there are some people who get grumpy when you post more than one non-community-wiki answer to a question, even when you did all of the work for those answers yourself.

Comment: @kaya3:  Why should I care if someone "gets grumpy"?  That's their problem, not mine.

Comment: @Miscellaneous You should not just blindly copy the content written by others, that is plagiary (and a copyright violation).

Comment: Mark has a good point here - just copying content from another site may violate the license of that site/user. I would recommend against it, unless that license explicitly allows you to do so.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Absolutely. That's why at first I only considered leaving the link to the content in the comment.

Comment: @Miscellaneous: A link in a comment to the external Q&A that has an answer is *much* better than nothing.  If you don't think the question looks valuable enough to future readers to do more than that (or you don't have time), just comment a link.  Otherwise, it could be worth figuring out how much of an external answer you can reasonably quote (with quote formatting, attribution, and a link) and making a community-wiki answer.